# How to get out of camera view?

Tags: camera, workflow, navigation

After I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>NumPad 0</kbd>, I go into the camera view. After that, I want to get out of the camera view, but don't know how to do it!

So how can I get out of camera view?

Comment: Hit NumPad 0, for instance

Comment: Can you turn it to a answer so I can approve it?

Comment: You can also hit and drag `MMB` to activate panning; viewpoint will exit from camera view.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get out of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>NumPad0</kbd> which goes in camera view, you can use any "moving" command <kbd>MMB [image: MMB]</kbd> (or <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>LMB [image: LMB]</kbd>, if *Emulate Three-Button Mouse* is enabled, which it typically is for touchpad setups. It is enabled by selecting Emulate Three-Button Mouse under the *Input* tab in the Blender User Preferences.)

Some numpad commands :

<kbd>Home</kbd> center 3D View

<kbd>NumPad0</kbd> camera Perspective

<kbd>NumPad1</kbd> front ortho

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>NumPad 1</kbd> back ortho

<kbd>NumPad3</kbd> right ortho

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>NumPad3</kbd> left ortho

<kbd>NumPad7</kbd> top ortho

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>NumPad7</kbd> bottom ortho

<kbd>NumPad5</kbd> toggle between perspective and ortho

<kbd>NumPad 4/6, 2/8</kbd> roll scene left/right, up/down

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>NumPad 4/6, 2/8</kbd> scroll scene left/right, up/down

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>NumPad 4/6</kbd> roll scene clockwise / anti-clockwise

<kbd>NumPad+</kbd> zoom in

<kbd>NumPad-</kbd> zoom out

<kbd>NumPad.</kbd> focus on the selection

Comment: Scrolling while in camera view will zoom camera view, nothing else. `Alt`+`LMB` is some new shortcut I heard for the first time.

Comment: @MrZak, for Alt+LMB I am using a touchpad, that may be why... I feel it easier as near to the keyboard... ok for scrolling though

Comment: `Ctrl` + `Numpad 0` sets the active object as camera and actives the camera (Blender 2.8+). It's not the same as `Numpad 0` (toggle camera). Getting out of the camera view will still leave you with the object that you had selected (such as a cube) set as the camera.

Answer (score 3):

For laptops, to exit the camera perspective either go to *View > Frame all* or press <kbd>Numpad 0</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

You can both enter and exit the camera view by pressing <kbd>~</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>. This is especially useful when you don't have a numpad or if you want to toggle back and forth between the camera and another view.